# Remove space on a table cell for a nested Table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to do a nested-table I'm about to be finish on my first `table` 
when this happen:

[image: SS]

here Is my HTML markup:

```
   <table class="quotationTable1">
    <%--Primary table--%>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <%--Second Table--%>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 397px">
                        <table style="border-style: solid; border-color: inherit; border-width: medium; width: 452px;">
                            <%--Third Table--%>
                            <tr>
                                <th colspan="2" style="padding-top: 5px; background-color: black; color: white;">Job Quotation</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2" style="height: 26px;">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblDescCategory" runat="server" Text="Category:"></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    <asp:Label ID="labelDescType" runat="server" Text="Type:"></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width: 265px">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblDescAddress" runat="server" Text="Address:"></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td style="width: 202px">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblDescContacts" runat="server" Text="Contacts:"></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2" style="height: 3px">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblDescJobdesc" runat="server" Text="Job Description:"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2" style="height: 59px">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="File: "></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Finishing:"></asp:Label></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <table style="width: 373px; position:relative;"><%--fourth table--%>
                            <tr>
                                   <th colspan="3" style="padding-bottom:5px; background-color: black; color: white; width: 400px;">Specification</th>
                            </tr>    
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How can I make my second `table` **Specification** remove all those spaces and
be on the same position as **Job Quotation**?

Comment: Please post your code or we will not be able to help you.

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: Do you want the table nested within the first table, so that the `Specification` table is within the `Job Quotation` table, directly under the `Job Description` row? Or do you want the tables to be level across the top? My answer assumes the first scenario.

Comment: the one @dippas gave me is the solution I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add `vertical-align:top` to `td`

and don't use inline styles, use classes instead

```css
td {
  vertical-align: top
}
.w400 {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width: 400px
}
.w397 {
  width: 397px
}
.w397 table {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: inherit;
  border-width: medium;
  width: 452px
}
.w397.title {
  padding-top: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
.w373.relative {
  width: 373px;
  position: relative
}
.h59 {
  height: 59px
}
.h26 {
  height: 26px
}
.h3 {
  height: 3px
}
```

```html
<table class="quotationTable1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td class="w397">
            <table class="w397 table">
              <tr>
                <th colspan="2" class="w397 title">Job Quotation</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="2" class="w397 h26">
                  <asp:Label ID="lblDescCategory" runat="server" Text="Category:"></asp:Label>
                  <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                  <asp:Label ID="labelDescType" runat="server" Text="Type:"></asp:Label>
                  <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="w265">
                  <asp:Label ID="lblDescAddress" runat="server" Text="Address:"></asp:Label>
                  <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="w202">
                  <asp:Label ID="lblDescContacts" runat="server" Text="Contacts:"></asp:Label>
                  <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="2" class="h3">
                  <asp:Label ID="lblDescJobdesc" runat="server" Text="Job Description:"></asp:Label>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="2" class="h59">
                  <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                  <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="File: "></asp:Label>
                  <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                  <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Finishing:"></asp:Label>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
          <td>
            <table class="w373 relative">
              <tr>
                <th colspan="3" class="w400">Specification</th>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: where will I add it?

Comment: in CSS just like I added in my snippet

Comment: it work!I did use inline so I could adjust some table cells specifically though.Is it wrong?

Comment: Not the best practice! I'm updating my answer to remove the inline styles.

Answer (score 0):

You need to nest the table in a `TR` and `TD` within the parent table:

```
   <table class="quotationTable1">
    <%--Primary table--%>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <%--Second Table--%>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 397px">
                        <table style="border-style: solid; border-color: inherit; border-width: medium; width: 452px;">
                            <%--Third Table--%>
                            <tr>
                                <th colspan="2" style="padding-top: 5px; background-color: black; color: white;">Job Quotation</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2" style="height: 26px;">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblDescCategory" runat="server" Text="Category:"></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    <asp:Label ID="labelDescType" runat="server" Text="Type:"></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width: 265px">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblDescAddress" runat="server" Text="Address:"></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td style="width: 202px">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblDescContacts" runat="server" Text="Contacts:"></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2" style="height: 3px">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblDescJobdesc" runat="server" Text="Job Description:"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                <table style="width: 373px; position:relative;"><%--fourth table--%>
                                    <tr>
                                           <th colspan="3" style="padding-bottom:5px; background-color: black; color: white; width: 400px;">Specification</th>
                                    </tr>    
                                </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2" style="height: 59px">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="File: "></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Finishing:"></asp:Label></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```